# what does " local caching of data" mean in the context of this article?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

From the following paragraphs of Text——
(http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html),It mentions that sequential readable large files are not suitable for local caching. but I don't understand what does local here mean...

There are two assumptions in my opinion: one is Client caches data from HDFS and the other is datanode caches hdfs data in its local filesystem or Memory for Clients to access quickly. is there anyone who can explain more? Thanks a lot.

---

But while HDFS is very scalable, its high performance design also restricts it to a 
particular class of applications; it is not as general-purpose as NFS. There are a large 
number of additional decisions and trade-offs that were made with HDFS. In particular:

Applications that use HDFS are assumed to perform long sequential streaming reads from 
files. HDFS is optimized to provide streaming read performance; this comes at the expense of 
random seek times to arbitrary positions in files.

Data will be written to the HDFS once and then read several times; updates to files 
after they have already been closed are not supported. (An extension to Hadoop will provide 
support for appending new data to the ends of files; it is scheduled to be included in 
Hadoop 0.19 but is not available yet.)

**Due to the large size of files, and the sequential nature of reads, the system does 
not provide a mechanism for *local caching of data*. The overhead of caching is great enough 
that data should simply be re-read from HDFS source.**

Individual machines are assumed to fail on a frequent basis, both permanently and 
intermittently. The cluster must be able to withstand the complete failure of several 
machines, possibly many happening at the same time (e.g., if a rack fails all together). 
While performance may degrade proportional to the number of machines lost, the system as a 
whole should not become overly slow, nor should information be lost. Data replication
strategies combat this problem.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any real Mapreduce job is probably going to process GB's (10/100/1000s) of data from HDFS.

Therefore any one mapper instance is most probably going to be processing a fair amount of data (typical block size is 64/128/256 MB depending on your configuration) in a sequential nature (it will read the file / block in its entirety from start to end.

It is also unlikely that another mapper instance running on the same machine will want to process that data block again any time in the immediate future, more so that multiple mapper instances will also be processing data alongside this mapper in any one TaskTracker (hopefully with a fair few being 'local' to actually physical location of the data, i.e. a replica of the data block also exists on the same machine the mapper instance is running).

With all this in mind, caching the data read from HDFS is probably not going to gain you much - you'll most probably not get a cache hit on that data before another block is queried and will ultimately replace it in the cache.

Comment: a mapper here is the client to DataNode, so local caching means the mapper caches data reading from Hdfs, right?

Comment: Eitherway, whether it's caching the data on the client side, or within the data nodes memory, the probably hit rate on a cache entry is going to be rare, with a very short ttl in the cache before another block pushes it out

Comment: I see, the main point here is that neither way of caching works,thanks!